# Handle async promise before ngOnInit Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have a request that returns data for a table, which needs to be handled like a promise to wait until the data has been loaded. In order to load the data into the table I have to use async/wait, but this messes up all other functions/methods.

How to store the data in currentList without using async/wait on ngOnInit()? Or is there an other way?

```
async getEducationList(): Promise<any> {
  return this.educationList = await this.applicationClient.getEducations()
  .toPromise()
  .then((res) => {
    this.educationListAll = res;
  });
}

async ngOnInit() {
  await this.getEducationList();
  this.currentList = this.educationListAll;
}
```

Note - this.applicationClient.getEducations() is an Observable

Comment: Can't you subscribe and assign the data

Comment: you can use rxjs, and httpclientmodule in angular

Comment: "messes up all other functions/methods" how?

Comment: `this.currentList` and `this.educationListAll` basically hold same data as `res` is assigned to `this.educationListAll` and then to `this.currectList`. Why?

Comment: question.. why does it 'have to wait'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by wrapping the API call in an observable and then moved the code from ngOnInit to another function initTable.

```
getEducationList(): Observable<Education[]> {
  return this.applicationClient.getEducations();
}

initTable(data) {
  // Some code to handle the data
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getEducationList().toPromise().then(data => {
    this.loader = false;
    this.initTable(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have update my answer base on this you can still use `async / await`,in my answer when you got the data the second line `  this.initTable(data);` will run , give it a try 

Answer (score 4):

try this way

```
async ngOnInit() : Promise<void> {
  this.currentList = await this.applicationClient.getEducations().toPromise();
  this.initTable(data);
}

initTable(data) {
  // Some code to handle the data
}
```

Comment: Just a note, async functions are expected to return a Promise. In the case of `ngOnInit`, etc, I typically spec the function as: `async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {...}`

Comment: @Brandon typescript will infer the type of ngOnInit ‍♂️

Comment: I don't think it's a bad habit to write the return type, even if typescript can infer it. I normally do not expect to return a Promise from an ngOnInit so this it's just a way of catching the attention from other colleagues.