# ANGULAR: understanding how to await a response

Tags: angular, promise

Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I've read through multiple questions on how to subscribe to a response but am struggling to frame it in the context of my program.

Here, I am asking Okta for the user data (simple enough). What follows is me mapping the results to an array, then assigning the username to the first value and the userGroups to the userGroups. However, as expected, Angular fires this code before the response comes in. The userClaims != null is a stopgap to prevent Angular errors.

My specific question: how do I structure this request with these variables?

```
async ngOnInit() {
this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
this.oktaAuth.$authenticationState.subscribe(
  (isAuthenticated: boolean)  => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
  );

const userClaims = await this.oktaAuth.getUser();


if (userClaims != null) {
this.claims = Object.entries(userClaims).map(entry => ({ claim: entry[0], value: entry[1] }));
this.userName = this.claims[1].value;
this.userGroups = userClaims.groups;

console.log('ADMIN COMPONENT: userName ' + this.userName + ' is a member of : ' + this.userGroups);
}}}
```

EDIT: Here is the promise

```
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { OktaConfig } from '../models/okta.config';
import { UserClaims } from '../models/user-claims';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
export declare class OktaAuthService {
    private auth;
    private router;
    private oktaAuth;
    private config;
    private observers;
    $authenticationState: Observable<boolean>;
    // $userState: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(auth: OktaConfig, router: Router);
    /**
     * Checks if there is an access token and id token
     */
    isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean>;
    private emitAuthenticationState;
    /**
     * Returns the current accessToken in the tokenManager.
     */
    getAccessToken(): Promise<string | undefined>;
    /**
     * Returns the current idToken in the tokenManager.
     */
    getIdToken(): Promise<string | undefined>;
    /**
     * Returns user claims from the /userinfo endpoint if an
     * accessToken is provided or parses the available idToken.
     */
    getUser(): Promise<UserClaims | undefined>;
    // private emitUserState;
    /**
     * Returns the configuration object used.
     */
    getOktaConfig(): OktaConfig;
    /**
     * Launches the login redirect.
     * @param fromUri
     * @param additionalParams
     */
    loginRedirect(fromUri?: string, additionalParams?: object): void;
    /**
     * Stores the intended path to redirect after successful login.
     * @param uri
     * @param queryParams
     */
    setFromUri(uri: string, queryParams?: object): void;
    /**
     * Returns the referrer path from localStorage or app root.
     */
    getFromUri(): {
        uri: string;
        extras: NavigationExtras;
    };
    /**
     * Parses the tokens from the callback URL.
     */
    handleAuthentication(): Promise<void>;
    /**
     * Clears the user session in Okta and removes
     * tokens stored in the tokenManager.
     * @param uri
     */
    logout(uri?: string): Promise<void>;
    /**
     * Scrub scopes to ensure 'openid' is included
     * @param scopes
     */
    scrubScopes(scopes: string): string;
}
```

Comment: What function is this inside of? It should have the async keyword.

Comment: Thank you for responding. It's in the ngOnInit. It does have the async keyword.

Comment: '   async ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
    this.oktaAuth.$authenticationState.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated: boolean)  => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
      );''

Comment: Is `oktaAuth.getUser` returns a Promise? Posting code of that function would be helpful to understand how it works.

Comment: Have you tried having ngOnInit return a Promise<void> ?   eg, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925816/handle-async-promise-before-ngoninit-angular

Comment: @pindev, added!

Comment: @racraman, I haven't - will try now.

Comment: Hmmm I thought using async/ await was bad form when it came to angular and that it is better to use RxJS patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps a little. 
Remember that async/await is syntactic sugar to work with promises, to make them clean and "easy".

I made a very simple example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ijnmcd
Where I call The dancing clown 3 times, one with a promise, the other with async / await. With the example should be easy to implement your solution.

Remember to use try{}catch(e){} to catch errors with async/await.

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

By the way, remember that HttpClient is an observable, this means you will have to subscribe to it, if you want to use async/await, you will need to use  toPromise() instead of the subscribe();

Hope it helps.

Comment: THANK YOU. Your examples provided a model for me to follow and it's working!